# Setting up Apache cluster

Tags: apache, cluster-computing

I am new to web developing, so my question might be silly.
I want to set up an Apache cluster. I have four hardware machines and I want to distribute http requests load between them. Now on every machine I have installed Fedora.
For now it can be simple *load balance* cluster without any recovery techniques (in case of some hardware error on some servers). And of course I need open source (free to commercial use) software.
Any suggestions on what soft/tutorials/books I should look to learn how to set up environment like this?

Comment: You're new to web development, and you decided to kick in with 4 machines and clustered Apache?

Comment: Not me, my team leader wants to have some tests of such environment.
What can I do? I have to give him some.

Comment: ah, that's nice, unfortunately your question is more suited for Serverfault. The official Apache doc should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The O'Reilly book "Server Load Balancing" by Tony Bourke (now runs lbdigest.com) is the classic. Unfortunately it's a little dated. Maybe Tony will consider an update.

If you really want "no recovery techniques", basic DNS Round-robin might work for you but it's pretty crude. There's an open source project called Ultramonkey, but I haven't had a chance to mess with it. A lot of development has gone into commercial solutions which offer load balancing, high-availability, etc. Including the Coyote Point product (which I helped write). The appliance based products are actually quite affordable today.